# Wow.js Working on Images But Not Other Elements

Tags: javascript, animation

From what I've read, it should be possible to place wow classes on elements like divs and forms, but so far I've only gotten it to work on img tags.

The below code works:

```
<img src='blah.jpg' class="wow fadeInUp">
```

This code does not work:

```
<div class="wow fadeInUp">
```

I have the proper CSS file and JS file loaded and have made sure to add the Doctype HTML tag.

Is there something I'm missing?